# ';' expected.ts(1005) in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was creating a redirect function named `redirect()` and when I open the curly brackets it shows an error saying

> ';' expected.ts(1005)

Any reason? I'm not sure what ts(1005) means so I don't know what to do.[image: the error]

The error fixes when I put a semicolon but then in the browser, it shows an error saying

> Uncaught TypeError: redirect is not a function
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Although it could be a different error. (Solve if you can please)
Thanks

Comment: Please give a [mre] *as text*.

Comment: Is this a class method or a function outside of a class? Do you need `function redirect() { ... }` ?

Comment: We're going to need to see some more code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define a function, place the keyword `function` before `redirect()`.
A `;` is expected because without `function` the browser thinks it is a function **call**.
(Is 1005 the line number?)

Comment: No, 1005 is the typescript compiler's error code for "; expected", although it's usually written TS1005 not ts(1005)